# maven repository with BigQuery Simba JDBC Connector

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, google-bigquery

I'm starting new backend application that will operate on BigQuery.
Would love to check Simba JDBC Connector, but my main blocker is no Maven repository with it. It complicates startup significantly.
Does it always have to be downloaded installed manually or are there any active repositories with it?

Ps. I'm aware that I cloud run my own nexus repository and deploy it there, but want to avoid it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simba JDBC connector for BigQuery does not have a Maven repository. The jar files need to be downloaded manually right now.There is an ongoing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/180413368) that is being worked on. However, we cannot provide an exact ETA on when that feature will be available.

Answer (score 2):

If this helps I built a gradle project that produces a shaded jar with the bigquery dependencies and publish it to a private maven repo: https://github.com/josecsotomorales/bigquery-jdbc-maven-publish